# Issues with css height 100% for div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I have developed an aspx page in visual studio. My layout is something like this

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MasterContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <div id="setting_wrapper">
        <div id="settings_controls">
           <ul>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="user"> <span style="padding-left:2%"></span> USER MANAGEMENT</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="Admin"> <span style="padding-left:2%"></span> EMS</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="Others"> <span style="padding-left:2%"></span> PRODUCT</a></li>
                <li><span style="padding-left:2%"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="settings_container">
            <iframe id="settings_iframe">
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

If I give width and height 100% to settings_wrapper it works properly in chrome ,taking the width properly. But in IE and firefox `"width:100%"` is not taking up and I need to give `600px` for expanding the settings_control div. what could be the reason

css applied are

```
#setting_wrapper
{  
    position:relative;  
    /*background:yellow;*/  
    width:100%;  
    height:100%;  
    overflow:hidden;  
}



#settings_controls
    {  
        position:relative;  
        float:left;  
        width:20%;  
        height:100%;  
        /*background:green*/  
    }

#settings_container
 {  
   position:relative;  
   float:right;  
   width:80%;  
   height:100%;  
   /*background:blue;*/  
}
```

I even tried giving

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: whats the height of `<asp:Content>` ? try setting `100%` for this too.

Comment: Please share `settings_control` css styles also.

Answer (score 0):

apply `display: table;` which make sure to work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
#setting_wrapper {
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:100vmin;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

or thy this :

```
html, body {
height: 100vmin;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It's cool to use **viewport units**. but just beware of browser support... http://caniuse.com/#search=vmin

Comment: @Twiny twice its not working... As the div is taking a small amount of  height. the scroll bar is displayed for scrolling down the contents